# Evitar el submit en un formulario

Tags: jquery, ajax, eventos

es que tengo un formulario, y necesito evitar que se vaya por el submit si no cumple ciertas condiciones, este es mi js.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.validar', function (event) {

            var parametros = {
                "User": {
                    "username": $("#UserUsername").val()
                }};
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Desarrollo/admin/users/validar',
                data: parametros,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.error==true){
                        event.preventDefault();

                    } 
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
```

si pongo el `event.preventdefault()` al principio ps no se va por el submit pero si solo quiero que lo detenga si el campo ya existe.

Comment: Existe también la instrucción `event. stopPropagation ()` [más info](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) y `stopImmediatePropagation` [más info] (https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

Answer (score 1):

antes que nada, estas capturando un evento `click`para un elemento que tiene de clase `.validar` cuando un form puede ser enviado de varias formas (apretando la tecla enter por ejemplo) en base a esto, lo que debes hacer es capturar el `evento submit` del form y segundo punto que tengo que decirte es que al parecer tu función que valida esta en el servidor (no entiendo la lógica de esto) por lo que debes detener el `submit` del formulario, usar tu validacion en servidor y luego si pasa volver a ejecutar el submit (si realmente es así como lo quieres)

un código de ejemplo sería:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit.php" onsubmit="funcionSubmit(event)">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

function funcionSubmit(event){
    // esta linea detiene la ejecucion del submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // tu funcion ajax
    $.ajax({
                url: '/Desarrollo/admin/users/validar',
                data: parametros,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.error==true){
                        // si error es true no hacemos nada porque ya detuvimos el submit
                    } else {
                        // si no hubo error volvemos a llamar el submit
                        // aquí no se si lo que quieres es hacer el submit nativo o uno tuyo propio
                        // submit nativo
                        event.target.submit();
                        // un submit propio seria con una llamada ajax o algo por el estilo
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: event.target.submit is not a function
    at String.<anonymous> (ProcessesScript.js:185)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:360)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (ProcessesScript.js:180)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)`

Comment: ok el método submit solo lo tienen los form, así que probablemente ejecutaste ese método al presionar un botón, de nuevo, lo que debes capturar es el `evento submit` del **formulario (html tag form)**, un boton por el simple hecho de estar dentro de una etiqueta `form` al hacer clic en el, va a ejecutar el evento `submit` del formulario, en base a esto no tienes que capturar ningún evento en el botón, lo que debes hacer es capturar el evento `submit` del formulario como te muestro en el código en el formulario dentro de los atributos del formulario el que dice `onsubmit="funcionSubmit(event)"`

Answer (score 0):

yo para esto utilizo javascript, mediante el evento onsubmit en la etiqueta `form`, te recomiendo que hagas lo mismo.

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://www.website.com/site" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return miFuncion()">
        <input name="ruc" id="ruc" type="text">
        <input value="Click" type="submit">
    </form>
```

asi es como colocas el codigo html, y el codigo javascript hace las verificaciones que desees, asi no se envia hasta que este todo validado

```
    function miFuncion() {
        var pasavalidacion=false;
        if (pasavalidacion==false) return false; //si haces un return false no se enviara el formulario, caso contrario si haces un return true si se enviara
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que detener el submit desde el inicio por que la petición ajax es asíncrona lo que significa que el formulario se manda antes de que llega la respuesta del ajax

Una opción seria poner el `event.preventdefault()` al inicio(siempre detener el envió del formulario) y al recibir la respuesta de la petición ajax hacer el submit del formulario manualmente con: `$("#idDeTuFormulario").submit();` con el trigger [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) de jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.validar', function (event) {

    event.preventdefault(); // siempre detener el submit

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.error==true){
                // no hacer nada
            } else {
                // enviar formulario
                $("#idDeTuFormulario").submit();
            }
        }
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Esta funciona, con una excepción, como activo desde el js las validaciones del html5 que se hacen automáticas con el submit?